# Mount persistent disk to /home in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, mount

Is there a way to mount a persistent disk to /home directory?

I've followed instructions from GCP (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk) that allows me to mount the disk to /home directory initially.
Then after I copied all the files from original home directory to the mounted /home, restart instance, I can no longer access the server using browser ssh tool anymore.
I've tried:
  1. Mount the disk directly to /home
  2. Mount the disk else where and create a soft link link to it

I can create files and folders and everything works just fine in the newly mounted /home before I power off the instance.  Once the instance is off and back online, I wont be able to ssh to it anymore with the message - "Unable to Connect, Retrying (2/3)..."

Has anyone with luck to mount a disk to /home successfully?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try first mounting the disk to `/mnt`, then copy your files from `/home` to `/mnt`:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
sudo rsync -avHAX /home/ /mnt/
```

If everything got copied correctly, then you can delete the folders in `/home`:

`sudo rm -rf /home/*`

Then, unmount the disk from `/mnt` and mount it to `/home`:

```
sudo umount /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home
```

(assuming `/dev/sdb1` is the partition you're trying to mount)

Configure `/etc/fstab` so that the `/home` partition will mount properly on boot.
See for example https://www.tecmint.com/move-home-directory-to-new-partition-disk-in-linux/